# How to read string array value using linq where clause instead of foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use linq where clause for the below code. I have tried foreach loop, its working perfect. But large amount of data the foreach loop takes more time to process. Please give any your valuable suggestion to get result by using linq where clause.

```
string path = @"D:/NewFolder";
var _path = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (var file in _path)
{
   foundFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
   if (foundFile == PumpSelectedItem.PumpGuid)
   {
      fileName = foundFile;
      isValidFileFound = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you think linq would make it any faster.

Comment: Instead of foreach loop the linq is easiest way I think. Please give any suggestion for making this linq where clause.

Comment: Each path contains two different files@Rufus

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "each path". There's only one path shown. I deleted my comment already, but why does that matter? You aren't doing anything with the files except setting a Boolean. @jhayden posted a similar answer.

Comment: Use should put `break` in the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work slightly better. Note that I use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`.

```
var fileName = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
    .Where(f => f == PumpSelectedItem.PumpGuid)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

`fileName` is null if no file is found.

I'm assuming you want to stop looking when you've found your first match.

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Where(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p) == PumpSelectedItem.PumpGuid).FirstOrDefault()`?

Comment: @JohnyL If you really want to, of course, do it. You could even put that lambda inside the `FirstOrDefault`, to get rid of the `Where`as well. But imho, the way I wrote it is my preferred way since I think it is much more readable. I also believe that any such transformations has only miniscule effects on the runtime efficiency (if any!) of the entire statement.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the loop is fine, but the *functional* equivalent in Linq would be:

```
fileName = _path.Select(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)) 
                .Where(fileName => fileName == PumpSelectedItem.PumpGuid)
                .LastOrDefault(); 
isValidFileFound = (fileName != null);
```

Note that the reason I use `LastOrDefault` is because *you keep looping after finding a file*, so the last file found will be your result. If that is not your intent then you can use `FirstOrDefault` or change your loop to break once one is found.

> But large amount of data the foreach loop takes more time to process

Linq is not going to make it any faster. What will make it faster is *stopping when you find the first matching file*. `FirstOrDefault()` will effectively do that, as will adding a `break` to your `foreach` loop. If no file is found, the performance will be the same either way (it will loop throuh all of the files).

Comment: That is not equivalent code, though... the original code is effectively setting `fileName = PumpSelectedItem.PumpGuid;`, while you are setting it to the full path of the file.